# How to convert AWSTimestamp into python datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, aws-appsync, awstimestamp

How to convert `AWSTimestamp` into python DateTime?

I am using [AWS AppSync scalar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html) type `AWSTimestamp` for datetime

Example:

```
2021-02-02T16:00:00-07:00
```

How to convert the above format to python datetime?

Comment: This is ISO format with timezone. Default datetime module handles it well - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat (click for specific classmethod and examples!)

Comment: Getting this error ` AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'`

Comment: What python version?

Comment: version -> Python 3.6.9

Comment: "New in version 3.7." 1. Consider updating. 2. Check if you have dateutils - it's external package but commonly comes preinstalled as it's really useful. `from dateutil.parser import isoparse` (https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) or just `parse` (https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: `ValueError: time data '2021-02-02T16:00:00-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.Z'`. dateutil.parser.isoparse('2021-02-02T16:00:00-07:00
') worked

Comment: @Thirumal your parsing directive is wrong; please have another look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Correct would be `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'` - but I suspect you'll require a newer version of Python to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `datetime.strptime(date_s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')`

Comment: ValueError: time data '2021-02-02T16:00:00-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00'

Comment: `+00:00` is not a valid here - use `%z` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser
dt = dateutil.parser.isoparse('2021-02-02T16:00:00-07:00')
```